# WPF Command binding to a static viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf

Firstly, I am new to WPF and MVVM, am trying hard to write well structured/separated code so please be kind.

I have created a user control and its own separate view model. In the view model I have an ICommand which relays to a method in the same viewmodel. I bind to this command in the XAML using System.Windows.Interactivity on an event like so:-

```c#
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Height="300"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1500"
             IsManipulationEnabled="True"
             Background="{StaticResource BackgroundWhiteBrush}">

    <Grid
        d:DataContext="{x:Static local:MyControlDesignModel.Instance}">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyViewModelCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </Grid>
```

My code behind (which I'm trying to leave as empty as possible) looks like this:

```c#
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            DataContext = ViewModelMyControl;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use this control in several pages. I also want to be able to call a method in this view model (passing a parameter) from other view models to allow it to update itself from a datastore.

I used a DI container to provide a reference to the view model so that I can a) reference its data loading method from another place and b) set that to the DataContext in the code-behind (above).

The implementation of the DI container provides this as follows:

```c#
 /// <summary>
 /// A shortcut to access the <see cref="MyControlViewModel"/>
 /// </summary>
 public static MyControlViewModel ViewModelMyControl => Framework.Service<MyControlViewModel>();
```

With this DI referenced viewmodel on the DataContext, the event/command does not fire.

If I change the code behind to as follows, the event/command does fire but then I lose the static reference which I was trying to have to "hold" the data between pages. I seem to be able to have events or static reference but not both.

```c#
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            DataContext = new MyControlViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the ViewModel lifecycle or perhaps binding in general. I have been following a lot of guides and now find myself stuck.

How do I have event/commands firing and also maintain a reference to the user control's data between pages which use it?

Comment: Suggest you not make the vm static.  Check your DI documentation for lifetime of injected objects.  For Autofac check LifetimeScope.  Not sure about other DI containers. In short you can tell your container to inject the same instance of an obect into multiple other objects.

Comment: Where is the static field ViewModelMyControl defined?

Comment: Also, there is nothing in the Grid in your example, which means there is nothing to click on, so no event fires.

Comment: @Sam I'll check the lifetime but are you suggesting that in my case, I shouldn't need to instantiate the vm in the control constructor?

Comment: @andrew - The static ViewModelMyControl is just defined in its own static class so I can get a reference to it where ever. Also the event trigger does work on the Grid, I can get it to fire but only in this case when I instantiate a new vm in the user control constructor.